# JavaScript: variable name unresolved

Tags: javascript

I wrote the following JS code:

```
function downloadFile(dataItem) {
    ....
}
....
for (var r = 0; r < dataItems.length ; r++) {
    table += '<tr>';
    var listOfAttributes = ['CarModel', 'BusMapping', 'Date_', 'Location_', 'Comments', 'AttackTraffic', 'IsTagged']
    **table +='<td> <a onclick="downloadFile(dataItems[r])" href="#">' + dataItems[r]['FileName']['S'] +'</a></td>';**
    for (var c = 0; c < Object.keys(dataItems[0]).length-1 ; c++) {
        table +='<td>' + dataItems[r][listOfAttributes[c]]["S"] +'</td>';
    }
    table+= '</tr>'
}
```

I get an error for the line:

```
table +='<td> <a onclick="downloadFile(dataItems[r])" href="#">' + dataItems[r]['FileName']['S'] +'</a></td>';
```

It seems that JS can't resolve the variable 'dataItems' inside the -tag:

```
<a onclick="downloadFile(dataItems[r])" href="#">.
```

However, later in the same line, JS resolves successfully the same name for the part:

```
+ dataItems[r]['FileName']['S'] +
```

What do you think can be the problem? How can I make dataItems be resolved inside the -tag ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: Could you please share the error message? Also please add any frameworks and other technologies you are using to the questions tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're placing a string inside the element's attribute it is not recognized as a JavaScript code or a JavaScript function so place the JavaScript function itself.

So you can do, `var anchor = '<a href="#" onclick="' + your_func_here + '"></a>';`

A sample example illustrating the problem, in this example if you write the function name as a string in the `onclick` property the function won't be called.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var element = document.createElement('a');
element.href = '#';
element.text = 'Fire!';
element.onclick = fire; // this invokes the fire function
// element.onclick = 'fire'; // this won't invoke the fire function
container.appendChild(element);

function fire() {
  console.log('fired');
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your variable is inside a string. Try changing the code to:

```
table +='<td> <a onclick="' + downloadFile(dataItems[r]) + '" href="#">' + dataItems[r]['FileName']['S'] +'</a></td>';**
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
<a onclick="downloadFile(dataItems[r])" href="#">
```

unless `dataItems` is a global variable, it won't be available to the environment which will make this call `downloadFile(dataItems[r])`, since onclick event will be invoked in a global scope.

You need to bind the event less intrusively this way

```
//you need to update the selector as per your markup
document.querySelector ( "tr td a" ).addEventListener( "click", function(){
  downloadFile(dataItems[r]);
})
```

Comment: But if you look at my code, you'll see that I have many <tr><td>...</td></tr>. How will the code "know" which one the onclick should be added to?

Comment: This is precisely why I mentioned that you need to update the selector based on your markup.